# How to get records that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables : 
Table A = PIECE_ASSY

```
id Component_Ref  BOM    PieceNum
1   ITEM:MAGNET   BOM1   CRCR1126
2   ITEM:FILLER   BOM2   CRCR5425
3   ITEM:SCREW    BOM1   CRCR2135
4   ITEM:MAGNET   BOM2   CRCR1127
```

Table B = Piece

```
id         Name            
CRCR1126     Magnet Assembly
CRCR5425     Filler Assembly     
CRCR2135     Screw Assembly
CRCR1127     Magnet Assembly
```

Now I am trying to get the list of Piece Id which doesn't have a specific Component_Ref and till now I have written this query

```
SELECT id
from Piece
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT p.id
                 from Piece p 
                 inner join PIECE_ASSY pa ON pa.PieceNum = p.id
                 WHERE p.id IN ('CRCR1126','CRCR5425')
                   AND pa.Component_Ref = 'ITEM:MAGNET')
```

Now my output that I am expecting is, the above query should return 'CRCR5425' since I passed ('CRCR1126','CRCR5425') and only CRCR5425 doesn't have the queried Component_Ref but instead it returns me CRCR5425,CRCR2135.

Now what I want is to get the Piece ID that doesn't have Component_Ref and instead of giving me all the Piece ID from table B, it should only output me those Pieces that are passed in the filter Parameter.

Comment: Can we have a real query, one that you've actually executed, rather than what you've put in this question please?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (I hope).

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM Piece p
WHERE p.id IN ('CRCR1126','CRCR5425') 
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM PIECE_ASSY pa WHERE  pa.PieceNum=p.id AND pa.Component_Ref='ITEM:MAGNET' )
```

Comment: Well, it might if you selected from the `Piece` table rather than the `Peice` one. The second of two clues why I know the OP (*still*) isn't showing us an actual query that they've run themselves. (They have since corrected the missing alias)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you for finding typo :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
SELECT id
from Piece p
WHERE id IN (SELECT PieceNum FROM PIECE_ASSY pa WHERE pa.PieceNum = p.id
                 AND p.id IN ('CRCR1126','CRCR5425') AND pa.Component_Ref <> 'ITEM:MAGNET')
```